OWASP ZAP not cleaning up after itself
I am using the OWASP ZAP api scan (zap-api-scan.py) script to scan my api using a swagger specification file. This works great and when the scan has finished I get presented with a nice report.
However, when the scan is finished I see that there is still a lot of junk entries left in the database which where made during the scanning.

My question is: Is there a way for OWASP ZAP to automatically clean up after itself? meaning that is automatically also deletes the entries it has made previously?
Thanks in advance!

Nope, sorry :)
We recommend that you have a specific test plaform for testing with ZAP.
Oh, and btw, ZAP is no longer part of OWASP...
